# jqgrid:data from the previous month can't appear

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

I don't know whats happen with my jqgrid,for the 1st time my data can show (all data which already input to database).

But, after I try to input date format from jquery datepicker like:
[image: datepicker]

I choose 08/03/2011 but actual date is 09/09/2011.
the jqgrid can't display that data, but in database the data is already input.
could you tell why its happen?

---

EDIT

this is for the input page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datePicker-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function() {
                        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                        });
  </script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="prob_date" class="datepicker">
```

and I get a downloaded folder `jqgrid_demo38`
and for the display page(use jqgrid):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

i'm just can't show the data which not inputed in the current month.

[Jqgrid](http://pastebin.com/DpQa3Rgy)

[dounfinish.php](http://pastebin.com/TDqCj7SG)

Comment: You should include the code which you use. The best is the code which can reproduce the problem.

Comment: which code, jquery or jqgrid?

Comment: It's a **very bad** question. You should include the *version nummer* of jQuery, jQuery UI, jqGrid which you use. The list of JavaScript files is also needed. Then you should include **your JavaScript code** (where you use jqGrid and the datepicker) which can be used to reproduce the described problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works....

I am Deleted some command in query:

```
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM oqc_defect ORDER BY $sidx $sord /*LIMIT $start , $limit*/";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldnt execute query.".mysql_error());
```

I am disabled `LIMIT` from query.

But, I don't know why it can works..may be another reader can explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Big guess here but I'm guessing you're trying to set a [maxDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate) on your datepicker. If that's so, then the date you're passing to maxDate is probably not correct.

Here's what I suggest to create a consistent date object for your maxDate across the various browsers:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="datetime" class="datetime" type="text" data-maxdatetime="<YOUR MAX DATE FROM DB HERE>" value="<SOME PRE-SELECTED DATETIME>" />
```

**JS:**

```
var max_date = $(".datetime").data("maxdatetime");
$(".datetime").datepicker({
  maxDate: parseISO8601(max_date)
});


/**
* http://jibbering.com/faq/#parseDate
* Parses string formatted as YYYY-MM-DD to a Date object.
* If the supplied string does not match the format, an 
* invalid Date (value NaN) is returned.
* @param {string} dateStringInRange format YYYY-MM-DD, with year in
* range of 0000-9999, inclusive.
* @return {Date} Date object representing the string.
*/
function parseISO8601(dateStringInRange) {
  var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s*$/,
      date = new Date(NaN), month,
      parts = isoExp.exec(dateStringInRange);

  if(parts) {
    month = +parts[2];
    date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
    if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
      date.setTime(NaN);
    }
  }
  return date;
}
```